# Compile-Time error while trying to use Linq to retrieve from DBModel (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620) tutorial called `Code-first to an existing Dabase` to use `Entity Framework`

Now, the only difference is that instead of creating a `ConsoleApplication` Project, I created a `Class Library` Solution in my Explorer with the Model from the existing `Database` that I am working on.

The model was created perfectly (All the Db classes are there). I added a `ConsoleApplication` to test the Model created.

So, in my solution explorer I have:

[image]

- `IdactConfigDb` is the model that I created from the tutorial.
- `ConsoleApplicationTest` The project with the reference to `IdactConfigDb`
- Notice that `IdactConfigDb` is referenced in the `ConsoleApplicationTest` solution.

Now, the problem comes when I try to run my test to retrieve the data in the Database. It does not allow me to `compile` the program. So, there must be a "reference problem".

Here is the solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IdactConfigDb;
namespace ConsoleApplicationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new IdactConfigModel())
            {
                var query = appSetting in db.AppSettings
                            orderby appSetting.Name
                            select appSetting;

                Console.WriteLine("All App Settings in DB:");

                foreach (var setting in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(setting.Name);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit:");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

```
Error   1   Invalid expression term 'in'      C:\Source\IdactConfigDb\ConsoleApplicationTest\Program.cs 15  40   ConsoleApplicationTest
Error   2   ; expected  C:\Source\IdactConfigDb\ConsoleApplicationTest\Program.cs   15  40  ConsoleApplicationTest
Error   3   ; expected  C:\Source\IdactConfigDb\ConsoleApplicationTest\Program.cs   15  43  ConsoleApplicationTest
Error   4   ; expected  C:\Source\IdactConfigDb\ConsoleApplicationTest\Program.cs   16  37  ConsoleApplicationTest
Error   5   ; expected  C:\Source\IdactConfigDb\ConsoleApplicationTest\Program.cs   17  36  ConsoleApplicationTest
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You missed the `from` keyword in your query.

Comment: Oh man. I feel dumb right now. I am very new to `Linq`!

Comment: You won't make that mistake again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typo:

```
var query = appSetting in db.AppSettings
            orderby appSetting.Name
            select appSetting;
```

Should be:

```
var query = from appSetting in db.AppSettings
            orderby appSetting.Name
            select appSetting;
```

Notice the missing `from` in your original query.

Comment: Thank you! As you said, that won't happen again :D